# MySQL: Query to get number of log entries per week -- including empty sets

Tags: mysql, reporting

My web application has a report that shows the number of logins by a particular user each week. However, I'm struggling to get the query just right. The problem I'm running into is that I can't seem to get the weeks during which the user did **not** login at all.

Currently my query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    DATE_ADD(logDate, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(logDate)) DAY) weekStart,
    DATE_ADD(logDate, INTERVAL(7-DAYOFWEEK(logDate)) DAY) weekEnd,
    COUNT(*) loginCount
FROM log
WHERE
    logDate > $startDate AND
    logDate < $endDate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a table for week numbers:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE weeks (weeknum INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then populate that table with integer values 0..53.

Then join it to your log table using the [`WEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function:

```
SELECT weeks.weeknum, COUNT(*) loginCount
FROM weeks LEFT OUTER JOIN log ON weeks.weeknum = WEEK(log.logDate)
WHERE log.logDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY weeks.weeknum;
```

If you need this query to support a date range that spans multiple years, use [`YEARWEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) instead, and populate your temp table with more rows in the YYYYWW format like values returned by `YEARWEEK()`.

Comment: I never responded to this because I never had a chance to test this -- other tasks and projects took priority. But it sounds good. :)